# parse string to custom date format c#

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing

I have trouble parsing a string to a correct DateTime. I am aware of DateTime.ParseExact but I keep raising exception. What did I miss here ?

```
const string formatString = "yyyyMMdd HHmmss";
const string fileName = @"C:\path.csv";

IEnumerable<Foo> dtos = File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
        .Skip(1)
        .Select(line => new {line, columns = line.Split(';')})
        .Select(t =>
        {
            try
            {
                return new Foo
                {
                    Bar = DateTime.ParseExact(t.columns[0], formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)
                };
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", t.columns[0])
            }
            return null;
        });
```

catch message is

> 20110102 170100 is not in the correct format.

EDIT : Link to a screenshot of the error as asked by helpers (SO don't let new accounts to add images).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSuIk.jpg)

Comment: `The value of t.columns[0] is shown in the caught message.` I don't think it is the value you think it is. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/yczKmH . The code clearly **works** with that value, and so if it doesn't work for you then it **can't** be that value.

Comment: I just tried your code against `string mydate = "20110102 170100";`. Guess what, it did work. Try to trim your `t.Columns[0]`, maybe it has some unwanted white space.

Comment: @mjwills I did edit it. It appear the problem is a double property and not the dateTime property. Thank you for the answers.

Comment: For another time, it's better to show your whole code. By not showing the double values that you're also parsing, we (including you) assumed that the date format is the problem.

Comment: @PaulKaram Yes, my bad, I did try to show minimal example, which is why I left out the other property, as I didn't think them relevant to the issue at hands. Good will poorly executed. An invariant culture in the double.Parse solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The code works.  You must be reading different data :

```
const string formatString = "yyyyMMdd HHmmss";
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "20110102 170100";
    DateTime Bar = DateTime.ParseExact(input, formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
}
```